# Code example for using Rebus with Azure Service Bus, Queue and Topic

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, rebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am new to `Rebus`, I am looking for code sample for using `Rebus` with `Azure Service Bus`, `Queue` and `Topic`.

I cannot see it from the link below:
https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples

**Update**

To start off: Sample of enqueuing and dequeuing messaging to Azure Service Bus for Queue, and Topic, configuration.

Ideally, cover more areas of Azure service bus, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use Azure Service Bus with Rebus, you can literally get going with something as simple as

```cs
services.AddRebus(
    configure => configure
        .Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBus(connectionString, "my_queue"))
);
```

using [Rebus.ServiceProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rebus.ServiceProvider/) with Microsoft's generic host, or

```cs
Configure.With(activator)
    .Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBus(connectionString, "my_queue"))
    .Start();
```

where `activator` is either Rebus' `BuiltinHandlerActivator`, or a [container adapter](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Container-adapters) for your favorite IoC container.

You might want to check out [the wiki page about the Azure Service Bus transport](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Azure-Service-Bus-transport) – it shows the basics of the configuration, and also explains some more stuff about e.g. long-running message handlers.

Comment: I came across the link https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Azure-Service-Bus-transport before I posted the question here. I thought there were samples from this link https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples. Are there samples that are not showing Azure Service Bus, but can be used for Azure Service Bus with some modification?

Comment: Pretty much all of the samples can be changed to use Azure Service Bus, if you replace whichever `.Transport(t => t.Use...)` is there with `.Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBus(...))` – although you will need to remove some parts, if they're also configured, like `.Subscriptions(s => ..)`, because Azure Service Bus does not need that configuration due to built-in pub/sub

Comment: I was also looking for a working Azure Service Bus example, and tried to apply @mookid8000 's suggestion and updated the RabbitTopics sample application to use Azure ServiceBus. When I then start the program, I see the following error in the console: An error occurred when attempting to receive the next message: "System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

Comment: I'll create an issue for this with more details.

Comment: Should I use topics? Or just queues?

Comment: @Enrico depends on a bunch of things  e.g. if you can say that the message is a COMMAND (i.e. it's instructing someone to do something), then send it to a queue – if you can say that the message represents an EVENT (i.e. a description of something that has happened), then publish it... when you think some more about these things, you'll find that many of your message types are either commands or events